# How to use FragmentTransaction's add() method to set a Fragment in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I'am using a drawerLayout that slide from right to left and to accomplish this task I'have created below's method :

XML code :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code :

```
public class ProfileActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
....
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

RelativeLayout drawerView;
RelativeLayout mainView;
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ............. //
    .............//
    drawerView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerView);
    mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            mainView.setTranslationX(slideOffset * drawerView.getWidth());
            mDrawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
            mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

}
  }
```

So I want to add Fragment in a RelativeLayout by code .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    View containerView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    ft.add(R.id.mainView, fragment);
    ft.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

You can probably call this code in your onCreate().

Comment: Thunks it works but with some changes ! but it did inspired me :D